# Intersection of commutator and radical

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra with radical $\mathfrak{r}$. It is claimed ([here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lie_algebra,_nilpotent), for example) that $$[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{r}] = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] \cap \mathfrak{r}.$$

The inclusion $\subseteq$ is pretty clear. I am not sure how to prove the reverse $\supseteq$. I know how to show that the intersection $[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] \cap \mathfrak{r}$ consists exactly of those $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ that act trivially in every irrep, but I don't see how to prove that $[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{r}]$ has this property so this doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: This is shown in Bourbaki, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149391/on-radicals-of-a-lie-algebra).

Comment: Dear Dietrich, The equation $\mathfrak{s} = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] \cap \mathfrak{r}$ appears in Bourbaki ( I.5.4, Theorem 1). I am not sure that $[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] \cap \mathfrak{r} = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{r}]$ is proved there.

Comment: But he continues in the post saying: "He also shows that $\mathfrak{s}=[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{r}] = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] \cap \mathfrak{r}.$" I think it comes later. I will look it up if I have time.

Comment: Dear @DietrichBurde , Indeed, it does come later! Thank you for the hint. I see now that this is I.6.4, Proposition 6. It seems the proof requires some additional tools.

Comment: You can answer your own question and present a proof of Proposition 6. I think that it will be useful for several other people here. The first containment if trivial, as you say, because $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{r}]\subseteq \mathfrak{r}$ by the ideal property.